# Adding file size limit in yii Filefield

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, limit

I'm trying to add a size limit for uploaded files in my filefield. I cant seem to find any resource on adding limits on filefields. This is my script:

for the view:

```
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'resume',array('class'=>'real-input hide','onchange'=>'getFilePath(this)')); ?>
```

for the model:

```
  array('resume', 'file', 'types'=>'txt,pdf,doc,docx'),
```

I want to put a file size limit of 2mb per upload, and if it would exceed 2mb, how do I add an error message to say that it exceeded 2mb?

Answer (score 1):

After much research, found out that you just need to add maxSize to the rules.

```
`array('resume', 'file', 'types'=>'txt,pdf,doc,docx', 'maxSize'=>2097152, 'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 2MB'`),
```

But be wary though that you must still check the PHP settings if you want to increase the limit.